# Eex шаблоны в prod

Tags: elixir

В проекте используются template.eex файлы, которые генерируют что-либо. Расположены они например в lib/my_app/templates/

Обращение к ним в dev окружении происходит напрямую, например render("lib/my_app/templates/template.eex", args).

Но в окружении prod они не доступны, файлы не найдены. Как их упаковать или как к ним обращаться, чтобы в prod они также были доступы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используешь релизы, то перемести все в папку priv
https://elixirforum.com/t/including-data-files-in-a-distillery-release/2813